# Prove by mathematical induction $u_{n} = 3^{n} - 2^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, induction, recurrence-relations

> Let $u_1 = 1$, $u_2 = 5$ and for $n > 2$ define $u_{n+1} = 5u_{n} - 6u_{n-1}$.
>
> Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb N$ we have:
> $$u_n = 3^n - 2^n$$ using mathematical induction.

Comment: This should hopefully be a routine exercise in using mathematical induction.  Have you seen any other induction proofs before?  What steps must you take to write a proper induction proof?  Where did you get stuck in your efforts so far?

Comment: What have you tried? They have told you how to do it, you should at least have gotten started.

Comment: You may be wondering how to get the expression $3^n-2^n$ without knowing it. Notice that the solutions of $x^2=5x-6$ are $3$ and $2$. That's not a coincidence. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Roots_of_the_characteristic_polynomial) -- the solutions of $a_n=Aa_{n-1}+Ba_{n-2}$ are given by $a_n=C\lambda_1^n+D\lambda_2^n$ if $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$, where $C,D$ are constants created by $a_0,a_1$, and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the solutions of $\lambda^2-A\lambda-B=0$ (the characteristic polynomial), and $a_n=C\lambda^n+Dn\lambda^n$ if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=1$ and for $n=2$ it's true.

Let $u_n=3^n-2^n$ and $u_{n-1}=3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$ for all $n\geq2$.

Thus, $$u_{n+1}=5u_n-6u_{n-1}=5(3^n-2^n)-6(3^{n-1}-2^{n-1})=$$
$$=5(3^n-2^n)-2\cdot3^n+3\cdot2^n=3^{n+1}-2^{n+1}$$
and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* A twist to the standard induction proof is to prove that $v_n=3^{n} - 2^{n}$ satisfies the same recursion with the same initial values, which is easier.

Comment: Which is exactly what a proof by induction would do, it's just another way to think about it as you do it.

Comment: @Arthur, exactly.